# Tkinter widgets created in an Update function run by tk.after function do not create untill the aforementioned Update ends

Tags: python, asynchronous, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I intend to make a Py code which creates a tkinter dot that turns on a key press and deletes on a key press of couple keys.
The dot already is functional but i need it switch on and off on certain keypresses/mouse clicks which means i need an outside tkinter.mainloop() Update function.
The Update function with a while in it to constantly check if conditions to turn it off/on are present. But the Tkinter widget Somehow gets applied to the screen Only when the function nds. Like widget could be created but it will only take effect when function ends. And i need to turn it off/on dynamically.

I have tried to use a tkinter.after() with additional one at the end of called function only to find out an error of Recursion depth. What i expected to happen was that the function would be called over and over again, instead it runs that function like a while loop. I also have tried Asyncio.run() but it would result not making it visible till the function ends at least once. And I need to change it dynamically.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Canvas
from winsound import Beep
from time import sleep
import asyncio
import keyboard
import mouse

root = Tk()

width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()

class tk_Dot():
    def __init__(self,x=-1,y=-1,radius=4,color="red"):
        self.x = x
        if x == -1:
            self.x = width/2-radius//2
            print(self.x)
    
        self.y = y
        if y == -1:
            self.y = height/2+radius//2
            print(self.y)
    
        self.radius=radius
        self.color = color
        self.lines = []
        self.count = 1
    
    def line(self,i):
        return canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y-i, self.x+self.radius, self.y-i, fill=self.color)
    
    def create(self):
        self.lines = []
        for i in range(0,self.radius):
            self.lines.append(self.line(i))
    
    def delete(self):
        for i in range(0,self.radius):
            canvas.delete(self.lines[i])
            canvas.dtag(self.lines[i])

opacity_of_tk_window = 1 # From 0 to 1    0 meaning completely transparent       1 meaning everything created in canvas will give the color it was given
root.attributes('-alpha',opacity_of_tk_window)

# Invisible Tkinter window label
root.overrideredirect(True)
# Makes Transparent background
transparent_color = '#f0f0f0'
root.wm_attributes('-transparent', transparent_color)
canvas = Canvas()
# Rectangle filled with color that is specified above as the transparent color so practically making transparent background
canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, width, height, fill=transparent_color)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

radius = 2
radius = 1+radius\*2

# Create a dot class
game_dot = tk_Dot(width/2-radius//2+1,height/2+1+radius//2,radius,"Red")
# Create a Dot at the middle of the calorant crosshair
# game_dot.create()
# Delete the dot
# game_dot.delete()


def Update():
    game_dot.create()
    print("Dot should be visible by now")
    print("Is it?")
    sleep(5) #sec
    print("Oh yeah after the function ends.") # the problem

def Delete():
    game_dot.delete()


root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, -2,-2))

# Tkinter window always on top

root.attributes('-topmost',True)
root.after(1000,Update())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `root.after(1000,Update())` immediately calls `Update()` and then passes the result to `root.after`.

Comment: This is simply how GUI frameworks work.  When you make a change to the GUI state, that doesn't do ANYTHING immediately.  It just sends a message.  The message will sit in the message queue until you get back to the mainloop, at which point the message will be dispatched to whichever GUI element needs to handle it.  And yes, you want `root.after(1000,Update)`.  Pass the function object, don't call the function.